# Yii2: filter criterias from two different tables

Tags: yii2, filtering, date-range

I have two tables on my database: `customer` and `payment`.

On `customer` table I have `city` and `region`columns. On `payment` table there are `amount`, `payment_date`, `customer_id` columns.

I need to make a statistics page using range date picker, cities and regions dropdown lists. User should be able to get the sum of the payments by selected cities, regions and date range.

I'm using Yii2 with Kartik Gridview and Kartik Date Range.

I can't figure out how to implement this.

Comment: [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) - Please read this and edit question. We won't write code for you.

Comment: I don't want anybody to write code for me. I'm just starting to learn. I'm completely new to mvc. I need some sort of instruction or an idea. I'm confused about $model variable and where originally it's declared (where comes from). After some reading now I guess I have to filter data in PaymentSearch. I just don't know where to start and what to do.

Comment: [The Definitive Guide to Yii2](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-index.html) - here's something for you. You can't start without fundamentals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to use data from another table. I know it's super simple, but I'm just writing this in case someone needs this info.

I just used `Customer` model in my `Payment` controller (inside my statistics action), and called the city names from the Customer table like this:

`$cities = Customer::find()->select('city')->asArray()->distinct()->all();`